# Get specific children with name into array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get all childrens and sub childrens of a parent gameObject by their names. Few children have a specific name and I am trying to get all them and store in an array. How do I achieve this?

```
    public GameObject[] Storage;
    
    void Start()
    {
        var childrenOfParent = this.GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>();
        foreach (var child in childrenOfParent)
        {
            if (child.name == "NAME OF THE CHILD ")
            {
                Storage= child.gameObject; //Not working
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Taken into consideration, I am using List instead of array and this is how I have progressed so far. There is no addition to my list. Am I doing it right? It seems like it is not searching all the children (especially sub childrens of sub parents). How do I achieve this?

```
public List<GameObject> Storage= new List<GameObject>();

foreach (Transform child in transform)
         {
             if (child.name == "NAME OF THE CHILD")
             {
                 Storage.Add(child.gameObject);
             }
         }
```

Comment: Note that `GetComponentsInChildren` also returns the parent object itself .. might be undesired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the quantity of child you'll store you can use the convenient `List` object insteed of an `Array`.

```
public List<GameObject> Storage = new List<GameObject>;
```

And then you add them like this :

```
Storage.Add(child.gameObject);
```

If you want to use an Array, you should first count how many children you'll have then create the array like this :

```
Storage = new GameObject[numberOfChild];
```

Then you can add `GameObject` to the array :

```
Storage[index] = child.gameObject;
```

But you have to know at wich index you want to save it. So everytime you add a child you must increment a `int index` variable for example : `index++;`.

Note that in you case you'll get only child of your parent, you'll have to make a recursive method to get child of child and so one.

**Advice**
If all theses childs already exist on editor time you should save their reference on editor time and not on runtime. You could just drag and drop them into inspector array or list. If you have too many to make it by hand you can make an method to do it for you on the `OnValidate` method for example and it will be executed on editor time everytime the object has a change.

**Answer to edited post**

Here's an example how get children of children recursively :

```
public class GetChildren : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> Storage = new List<GameObject>();

    public void Start()
    {
        string name = "NAME";

        Storage = new List<GameObject>();
        Storage.AddRange(GetAllChildrenRecursive(transform, name));
    }


    public List<GameObject> GetAllChildrenRecursive(Transform container, string name)
    {
        List<GameObject> childFound = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < container.childCount; i++)
        {
            var child = container.GetChild(i);

            if(child.name == name)
            {
                childFound.Add(child.gameObject);
            }
            childFound.AddRange(GetAllChildrenRecursive(child, name));
        }
        return childFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please kindly see my question as I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
Storage = GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>()
    .Where(x => x.name == "NAME OF THE CHILD") // Filter based on name
    .Select(x => x.gameObject) // Select child's GameObject
    .ToArray(); // Convert to array
```

Comment: Yes but I didn't know Unity actually allows to use `GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>()` .. it is limitted to `Component` which `GameObject` doesn't inherit from ... but apparently this works anyway ^^